# Search Scope returning aspx pages

Tags: 2010, search, search-scope, file

I have 40 document libraries. I dont want to add exclusion for each document library to exclude "http://pop.abc.com/sc/doclib1/Forms".

I tried adding fileextension = aspx exclude and that does not work (fileextension is checked for allow this to be used in scope)

I tried adding contenttype = folder with exclude and that did not help either.

What is the best way to do this without touching the farm level settings?

I want to exclude all the aspx pages in the forms folder and views too.

Comment: Also tried contentclass = STS_List_GenericList with Exclusion to prevent views to show up in the result but no help.

Answer (score 1):

http://prajapati-jatin.blogspot.com/2011/10/exclude-allitemsaspx-pages-from.html

This should have directions to exclude any .aspx file from search results

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I feel little dumb. I had to go to site collection settings and only pick the scope i wanted that site to use. Then my fileExtension=aspx exclusion rule worked.